# Execute a wsgi app from within another wsgi app via request method and store the html data

Tags: python, python-3.x

The idea behind my code is to add a counter at the end of data of each html file and wsgi_mod file running:
Counter is just adding that value bases on previous calculations.
The problem is that every time i try to load

```
superhost.gr/clientele 
or
superhost.gr/download
```

which i already have in httpd.conf an open mod_wsgi process for those 2 python apps
So every time app.py tries via request object to get the response of another wsgi app its keeps waiting and waiting for a long time until i ctrl-c

How will i be able to open via request method a wsgi app and return it in the form of html data?

=======================================================

```
@app.route( '/' )
@app.route( '/<page>' )
def index( page='index.html' ):

    # read environment
    pdata = ''

    if page == 'index.html' or page in ('clientele', 'downloads'):
        init()
        database( page )

    cur.execute( '''SELECT hits FROM pages WHERE url = %s''', page )
    pagehit = cur.fetchone()[0]

    # pick random line from the quote text file & random mp3 from the the music folder
    quote = random.choice( list( open( '/home/nikos/public_html/data/private/quotes.txt', encoding='utf-8' ) ) )
    music = random.choice( os.listdir( '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/mp3/' ) )


    # add counter to html template and start rendering
    counter = '''<table bgcolor=black    bordercolor=orangered>
                    <td><font size=3 color=lime> Αριθμός Επισκεπτών: </font></td>   <td><a href="%s"><font size=3 color=plum> %s </font></a></td>
                </table>
            ''' % ( url_for('log', page=page), pagehit )


    if page in ('clientele', 'downloads'):
        try:
            r = requests.get( 'http://superhost.gr/' + page )

            if r.ok:
                pdata = r.text + counter
        except Exception:
            sys.exit(0)

    elif page.endswith( '.html' ):
        pdata = render_template( page, quote=quote, music=music, page=page, pagehit=pagehit ) + counter


    return pdata
```

Comment: I have tried removing WSGIScriptAlias for /clientele and /download enirely as well as putting them beneath '/' alias but i'm still getting the same waiting and waiting when i try for example to invoke superhost.gr/downloads request from within.py

I understand the logic of python we apps.
Before moving to flask and mod_wsgi i was using the same approach for my 3 script when i was using cgi mode.

Comment: Let's say i have 10 mod_wsgi applications than need to be opened from within 'app.py' via requests.get and then take the html output of those and add my counter data to that, how do you suggest i woud do it?

Its not practical to take all of the ohter sapps code and place it into app.py code.